# MongoDB Could not connect to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am not able to connect remote mongodb from my asp.net application. Though I am able connect it through mongo console.It gives me following error

> "An exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException'
>   occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to connect to server troup.mongohq.com:10035: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Also I am able to connect my asp.net application from my local database.

Here is my code to connect mongodb by c#

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://appuser:xxxxx;@troup.mongohq.com:10035/PowrOfYouDev2";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("PowrOfYouDev2");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("Test");

        var entity = new Entity { Name = "Tom" };
        collection.Insert(entity);
        var id = entity.Id;

        var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(x => x.Id, id);
        entity = collection.FindOne(query);

        string str = entity.Name;
```

I am inserting image of error

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Could you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Way late... But is there a reason you had that semicolon in the path?

```
"mongodb://appuser:xxxxx;@troup.mongohq.com:10035/PowrOfYouDev2
```

Seems like it should have been:

```
"mongodb://appuser:xxxxx@troup.mongohq.com:10035/PowrOfYouDev2
```